# Unable to stub-out the dependency using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a simple test case where I want to mock out the object. However, for some reason I am getting Null Pointer exception as orderDaoImpl is not mocked out.

I am new to mockito any help in this regard is appreciated.

```
public class OrderBusinessImplTest extends TestCase {

    //Stub-out the dependency
    @Mock
    OrderDAOImp orderDao;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        //We need this because at runtime it will scan all the references of OrderDao and mock the object
        System.out.println("Hey");
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testPlaceOrder() throws SQLException, BOException {
        OrderBusinessImpl orderBusiness=new OrderBusinessImpl();
        orderBusiness.setDao(orderDao);
        //When is an important method which is used to mock out the object call
        Order order= new Order();
        //Set the expectations
        when(orderDao.createOrder(order)).thenReturn(new Integer(1));
        boolean results=orderBusiness.placeOrder(order);

        //Verify the results
        assertTrue(results);
        verify(orderDao.createOrder(order));
    }
}
```

Result:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at OrderBO.OrderBusinessImplTest.testPlaceOrder(OrderBusinessImplTest.java:40)

After debugging I found out that orderDao is null and when I am trying to call this orderDao.createOrder(order) it leads to an exception.

Comment: you need to add OrderBusinessImplTest annotations (or/and TestCase class annotations if have any)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason extending `TestCase` makes JUnit not run `@Before` method. You might have noticed that because you also have this log line there:

`System.out.println("Hey");`

If you really want to extend `TestCase` you need to move `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` (preferably as the first line) in your test method `testPlaceOrder` and get rid of your `@Before` method.

But even better alternative would be to add annotation:

`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

to your test class `OrderBusinessImplTest` (and remove `@Before` method) because then you would get mocks inited automatically (so without any `initMocks(this)`).

In any case think if you really need to extend `TestCase`?

**Also** your last verify should be like:

```
verify(orderDao).createOrder(order);
```